# Как с клавиатуры прописать символ гравис (диакритический знак)

Tags: mysql, sql

Как прописать вот символ Гравис с клавиатуры?

Аналоги на моей Клаве, которые есть, работают НЕ правильно:

```
MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE  `login` = @LU AND `password`= @LP", db.GetConection());
```

вот как эти  "   `    " одинарные кавычки прописать? на моей клавиатуре есть только
такие:       "   '    "   на примере кода, мне пришилось копировать символы и так вставить.

UPD : редактор этого сайта вовсе удаляет эти символы, по этому посмотрите в конце текста, где я показываю, какие есть на моей клавиатуре, а какие нужны

Comment: Если вы на винде - попробуйте этот драйвер для клавиатуры https://github.com/cajhin/capsicain
Через него можно переназначить любую клавишу или создать хоткей по которому будут печататься нужные вам символы.

Comment: Данный символ ` можно напечатать нажатием на английской раскладке на клавишу с тильдой(русское ё)

Answer (score 1):

Вариант 0: На Английской раскладке нажмите клавишу Тильда (обычно под клавишей Esc)

Вариант 1: ` - гравис (диакритический знак), для ввода удерживайте левый Alt и введите на бух. клавиатуре 96, отпустите Alt.
[Символы ASCII](https://www.ibm.com/docs/ru/sdse/6.4.0?topic=configuration-ascii-characters-from-33-126).

Вариант 2: Попробуйте не писать символ ` в запросе MySql.
Проверьте, работает ли следующий запрос у вас.

```
MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM users WHERE login = @LU AND password = @LP", db.GetConection());
```

Источник по синтаксису: https://www.w3schools.com/mysql/mysql_select.asp